# C# ConfigurationBuilder Get JsonObject

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-2.2

I have a Problem accessing the values of a JSON config file with the Configuration Builder
My JSON Looks like that

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "valueType": "taktzeit",
      "interval": 3
    },
    {
      "valueType": "werkzeugwechsel",
      "interval": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update**
It is in a folder called Config --> Config/config.json . I set the property, so the file is in the build folder

My Code:

```
var a = builder.AddJsonFile(Globals.ConfigPath).Build()
                .GetSection("item").GetChildren().ToList().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

This is what I get when I loop through "a"'

[image]

Don´t see what I am missing.
Thanks in advance

**Update 2**

My Model:

```
public class Config
{
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the Jason file in project ? Is it appsettings.json file ?

Comment: No, its a file in a folder: Config/config.json. I already set the file to be in the build. If I use....GetSection("item:0:valuteTyp").. I get whats inside the file. But I need it in a more generic way

Comment: Can we see the class that this is deserializing to? It seems you have "`x.Value`" in your LINQ, but "`valueType`" in your JSON.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: try this `var a = builder.AddJsonFile(Globals.ConfigPath).Build()
                .GetSection("item").Get<List<Item>>();` see if it return list f `Item`

Comment: thank you @Saif. Clean and simple :) I get my values now!

Comment: @Christian my pleasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change This

```
var a = builder.AddJsonFile(Globals.ConfigPath).Build()
            .GetSection("item").GetChildren().ToList().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

to

```
var a = builder.AddJsonFile(Globals.ConfigPath).Build()
            .GetSection("item").Get<List<Item>>();
```

this will result list of `Item`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all else is already configured, simply bind to the desired object graph.

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .AddJsonFile(Globals.ConfigPath)
                                    .Build();

Config config = configuration.Get<Config>();
```

#### Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)